# Slack for Windows - Something's not working

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, slack

I recently installed some updates on my Windows 10 machine. After rebooting and trying to launch Slack, I get this error:

[image: Something's not working]

I can open the slack web app just fine, but the desktop app consistently fails to open. How can I resolve this issue and get back to work?

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be caused by one or more of the background processes that Slack initializes on startup.

Open the Task Manager and sort processes by name. Look for any processes named "Slack".
[image: Slack Processes]

Select each item and click "End task".

Once all background Slack processes are stopped, you should be able to open Slack normally.